# Change color of mac menu bar with applescript

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to change the color of the top menu bar in mac with applescript?

[image: menubar]

Comment: Isn't that color just a transparent view of your desktop color?

Comment: Sounds like you're right. I've found some ("hacky" way of doing it) [http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/28/mac-black-menu-bar-os-x-obsidianmenubar/] but this sort of thing probably won't be possible to do with applescript. Would it atleast be possible to change the transparency of the menu bar with applescript?

Comment: There is a check box in System Preferences under the Desktop/Screen Saver settings. I'm sure there's a way to automate clicking that on or off. However it appears they took out that option in OS Yosemite because everything is translucent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In macOS Sierra 10.12+, the System Preferences includes a "Use dark menu bar and Dock" option under the General preference pane.

[image: Screenshot of Dark Mode]

In Applescript's dictionary you can see that this can be changed by setting a boolean called "dark mode".

A simple AppleScript to toggle dark mode would be:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell appearance preferences
        if dark mode is false then
            set dark mode to true
        else
            set dark mode to false
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```